# JavaScript randomly choosing 0 or 1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a couple of statements that chooses either 0 or 1

and I want 0 and 1 to have the equal possibilities

I did this

```
chosendirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
```

but the above does not choose 0.  It chooses 1 only.

Thanks!

Comment: No, that chooses `0` or `1`.

Comment: It seems your problem cannot be reproduced. Check the downstream code for how you treat `chosendirection` further on.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(Math.random())`

Math.random already returns a value between 0 and 1